# What is the unit of Signal as output in "nmcli dev wifi"

Tags: linux-networking, wifi, networkmanager

I want to know the unit in which The `Signal` is calculated. Is it in dBM ? Usually I see the dBM values are in `-`. What would the `-` and `+` values signify in dBM ? Also more the value is positive, does it mean more Signal Strength ? i.e would a value of `42` mean higher signal strength than a value `37` ?

```
 # nmcli dev wifi

*  SSID                              MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
*  nixcraft                          Infra  149   54 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA2     
   tfarcxin                          Infra  7     54 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SIGNAL** value is a percentage.

Maximum signal value is 100. You can test this by getting closer to the router.

If you want the output in dBm, use iwlist.

In this case, "-25" is better that "-50".